# why am I getting 'access forbidden' error after setting up virtual host in xampp?

Tags: windows, apache, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I have just installed a fresh installation of XAMPP for PHP version 7.4.7.0 on windows 10 64 bit but I'm getting an error message 'Access Forbidden' like this
[image]

the steps I did was:

1. added this code at the bottom of `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/Project/gotravelly/"
    ServerName dev.gotravelly.com
</VirtualHost>
```

2. added this code at the bottom of `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       dev.gotravelly.com
```

what am i missing? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well the error message gives you two possible causes for the problem. Have you investigated either of them? We can't see your folder contents, or the permissions set on it.

Comment: @ADyson the folder contains index.php, which I never edited since the project was created (I'm using CodeIgniter 3 so there was no need to mess with that file), and I've just removed the read-only attribute from the Project/ and Project/gotravelly/ folder and I've already restarted the Apache server, but I'm still getting the same error..